# Difference Between Filecontents and Filecontents* and When to Use One Instead of the Other

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, makeindex, filecontents, idxlayout

I have recently been experimenting with different ways to replace the comma in the Index with a different symbol. The following code replaces the said comma with a blank space.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
%delim_0 " $a$  "
delim_0 " $ $  "
%delim_1 " $b$  "
delim_1 " $ $  "
%delim_2 " $c$  "
delim_2 " $ $  "
delim_n ","
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{book}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Some words.\index{entryA}
Some words.\index{entryB!subentry}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the Index output:

[image]

*Remark:* I have also run the above code using `filecontents*` in place of `filecontents` with seemingly identical output.

QUESTION: Can someone explain the difference between `filecontents` and `filecontents*`; and when perhaps, it is advisable to use one instead of the other?

Thank you.

Comment: The difference is in the generated file. If you use `filecontents`, you will get a disclaimer on the top of the file that it was generated by the `filecontents`. In case of `filecontents*`, you won't get that.

Comment: filecontents here is just being used as a convenient way to keep it all in one file to post to this site, there's no reason to write the makeindex style from tex at all in general.

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you for passing along this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filecontents` (and its starred version) forms part of the LaTeX kernel, but was originally released as a separate package called [`filecontents`](//ctan.org/pkg/filecontents). As such, from its [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/filecontents):

> `filecontents` works much like `verbatim`, except that it takes a mandatory filename argument:
>
> ```
> \begin{filecontents}{myfile.tex}
> This text gets written to \texttt{myfile.tex}.
> \end{filecontents}
> ```
>
> The preceding code will write a myfile.tex file with contents resembling the following:
>
> ```
> %% LaTeX2e file `myfile.tex'
> %% generated by the `filecontents' environment
> %% from source `mydocument' on 2001/07/31.
> %%
> This text gets written to \texttt{myfile.tex}.
> ```
>
> `myfile.tex` can then be incorporated back into the document with `\include` or
> `\input`. Had `filecontents*` been used instead of `filecontents`, the file would
> have contained only the "`This text gets written to \texttt{myfile.tex}.`"
> line. `filecontents*` is therefore useful for writing non-LaTeX files such as Encapsulated PostScript files.

Another use-case for `filecontents*` comes from writing listings, where TeX comments might seem out-of-place, or where the syntax is completely different.

I personally prefer `filecontents*` since the commented description doesn't provide anything that cannot be incorporated into the filename, for example (like `20010731_myfile.tex`).

Comment: yes although latex2e has always had a built in filecontents, just that recent releases included some of the package extensions.

Comment: Many thanks @Werner